# Regex for matching URLs only outside href

Tags: c#, regex

I need a Regex to extract URLs starting with either "http://", "https://" or "www." from an HTML string. However, if such a URL occurs in an an `<a href=...>` attribute, it shall be ignored.

I tried with the Regex `@"\b(?:https?://|www\.)\S+\b"` but this still included the href strings:

```
var input = "<a href='//www.facebook.com'>www.facebook.com</a><br><br>https://www.amazon.in/<br>​<br><a href='http://www.google.com'>Testlink</a>​​​<br><br>https://in.yahoo.com<img src ='dev.salesrep.ly/Utility/GetLogoV1?CID=xx6&&PID=ukjh&&SID=4a9' height = 0 width = 0>www.ssd.com";

foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(input, @"\b(?:https?://|www.)\S+\b"))
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
}
```

**Expected output**

```
https://www.amazon.in 
https://in.yahoo.com
www.ssd.com
```

**Observed output**

```
https://www.amazon.in
https://in.yahoo.com<img src ='dev.salesrep.ly/Utility/GetLogoV1?CID=xx6&&PID=ukjh&&SID=4a9
```

Comment: any one please not getting regarding question ask me in a comment why you people directly decreasing

Comment: Your question is not very clear. The peace of code you give is not even legal C#. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @KlausGütter I need a regex for retrieve url's containing www or http:// but not href tag

Comment: I edited the question trying to make it clearer. Hope I understood you correctly.

Comment: Why don't you first remove all `href` attributes from the input string and apply the regex to the result?

Comment: @KlausGütter i want to add href tab for those url which not have that's the reson i want get without href tab url and modify that url with href

Answer (score 0):

Regex is not really the correct tool to parse HTML because - well - HTML is no regular language. probably a better solution would be to use some HTML parser like HtmlAgilityPack.
That said...

**Option 1:**
You could make your extraction work by first removing every `<a>` tag from the input

```
var input = "issuetesing www.abc.in sdsd <br> <a href='www.facebook.com'>www.facebook.com</a> <br>https://www.flipart.com";

var inputWithoutHyperlinks = Regex.Replace(input, @"<a .*?(/>|</a>)", "");
```

This will remove both `<a href='whatever'>whatever</a>` as well as the short form `<a href='whatever'/>`.

Then search only within this new string.

```
foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(inputWithoutHyperlinks, @"\b(?:https?://|www.)[\w+\.]+"))
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
}
```

Result:

```
www.abc.in
https://www.flipart.com
```

Note that I changed your Regex recognizing URLs slightly so that it stops at the first character which is not a word char or a dot (there are surely better Regexes for URLs).

**Option 2:**
But maybe you want something slightly different: compare all found substrings looking like a URL and remove those where an `<a href='...'>` is present?

```
var input = "issuetesing www.abc.in sdsd <br> <a href='www.facebook.com'>www.facebook.com</a> <br>https://www.flipart.com";

var allFoundUrls = new HashSet<string>(Regex.Matches(input, @"\b(?:https?://|www.)[\w+\.]+").Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Value));
var allHrefs = new HashSet<string>(Regex.Matches(input, @"(?<=<a\s+href=['""])[^'""]+").Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Value));

Console.WriteLine("Found hrefs:");
foreach (var url in allHrefs)
    Console.WriteLine("  {0}", url);
    
Console.WriteLine("Found URLs:");
foreach (var url in allFoundUrls)
    Console.WriteLine("  {0}", url);

Console.WriteLine("Found URLs without href:");
foreach (var url in allFoundUrls.Except(allHrefs))
    Console.WriteLine("  {0}", url);
```

Output:

```
Found hrefs:
  www.facebook.com
Found URLs:
  www.abc.in
  www.facebook.com
  https://www.flipart.com
Found URLs without href:
  www.abc.in
  https://www.flipart.com
```

Comment: can you please do one more favor for  Now, string partitioning space only on above       regex need to partitioning "<br>" and "< "icon also                                                                                                                                 
for below sample                                                                                                                           <a href="//www.facebook.com">www.facebook.com</a><br><br>https://www.amazon.in/<br>​<br><a href="http://www.google.com">Testlink</a>​​​<br><br>https://in.yahoo.com<img src ='dev.salesrep.ly>

Comment: If it works, you may consider accepting the answer.. As for your add-on question: I don't understand what you mean. Seems not related to me, so you should better create a new question for it.

Comment: it's related to existing question  exist regex separate string by space "\S" and I need to separate less than "<" also need space and <

Comment: Then please edit your question to include also this test case in the input string as well as in the expected output.

Comment: I have edited my question please review Klaus Gütter

Comment: Edited my answer with an improved regex